# Template parameter omitted?

Tags: c++, templates

I was looking into [this library](https://github.com/ben-strasser/fast-cpp-csv-parser) and the following piece of code caught my attention

```
template<class T>
void parse_float(const char*col, T&x){
    ...
}

template<class overflow_policy> void parse(char*col, float&x) { parse_float(col, x); }
template<class overflow_policy> void parse(char*col, double&x) { parse_float(col, x); }
template<class overflow_policy> void parse(char*col, long double&x) { parse_float(col, x); }
```

I see the function `parse_float` is templated with parameter `class T`. However, below the implementation of that function, there are some other templated functions that are calling `parse_float` but they do not pass the template argument to it. How is this possible? What value will `class T` will have?

Comment: Isn't most of the code you posted completely irrelevant?

Comment: The compiler will infer the template parameter when it can be deduced from the types of the arguments being passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ compilers are allowed to deduce template parameters for template functions under certain circumstances from the parameters you use to call that function.

So for example this

```
template<class overflow_policy> void parse(char*col, float&x) { parse_float(col, x); }
```

will deduce `T` to be `float` since `x` is of type `float`. (There are also a bunch of rules about whether it is a reference or not, but that's not necessary to get the general idea of how it works).